# YouTube storage design and implementation

Tags: youtube, storage

I'm currently researching the architecture behind YouTubes storage and I'm looking for sources of information on that subject but I'm having difficulty finding references to that subject so I'm wondering if some of you might have intel on that subject :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's BigTable on GFS now.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_File_System

more info here
http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture

Comment: I've found out that they are using BigTable for thumbnail storage according to [Seattle Conference on Scalability: YouTube Scalability](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-6304964351441328559#) but I also need information on the architecture behind the video storage part, there does not seem to be too much information laying around on that topic

Answer (score 1):

For such info I depend on High Scalability. You can browse thru this

http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture.

Needless to say its not an exhaustive description.